# Why is this question not closed?

Tags: discussion

[Leaving a job very early to accept another offer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/7406/leaving-a-job-very-early-to-accept-another-offer)

I don't understand why this question hasn't been closed. The core question is "Should I leave my current job for the other?"

How is this different from other "What job should I take?" questions?

(I'm just shooting for understanding here. I'm not lobbying for action either way)

Comment: It looks like I already voted to close this question. I'm really not sure what happened.

Comment: I voted to close as a dup...  It could have been made constructive but there were already answers that would have been invalidated by the edit...

Answer (score 1):

The difference between "Should leave current job for another" and "What job should I take" is that the first has the subject already in a job, while the other ask a second opinion on something that really can only be answered by the one asking on a personal level. The person who ask the question you refer to is asking for what I translate as an ethical judgement. Is it wise to leave a current job for a better and more tempting job? How will it look from a professional standpoint? The answer is yes, and it will not look too bad unless he/she leaves with both middle fingers raised shouting "F**k you all!".

In other words, it's an ethical question, not a personal choice question, even tho I do see your point that it looks a bit like that.

Answer (score 0):

I agree it should be closed, but because it's asking for opinions. "Should I leave my current job?"

The outcome is the same as if asking "which of the two should I go with?", but it's in fact a different question. I'm not saying, you're wrong, but giving a conceivable reason, why people might have shied away from flagging it as that first option or flagging it at all.

Comment: "Should I leave my current job for the other?" is functionally equivalent to "Should I take job A or job B?" where A just happens to be your current job. Right?

Comment: Not necessarily. The first question prompts me for my opinion on it *whether you should* do it. The second asks me to *choose from A or B*, not for my opinion on whether you shoul at all. The result may or may not be the same. You might give them a piece of your mind for the second, or just tell them A or B for the first question, but that's besides the point.

Comment: "Should I choose to stay at my job A, or go to job B?" I still don't see a fundamental difference.

Comment: If that would have been question there would be none. But it's academic. My post is agreeing with you and only suggesting a hypothesis oh why people didn't vote to close.